# Pyplot in notebook - chart does not update on events

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use notebook in a browser to run python code(pyplot, matplotlib) to generate charts that should update automatically on mouse movement, mouse click and timer. However, once I hit Cell->Run all, the image is generated once and remains static.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You could start by posting the simplest possible example that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Because the inline backend does not support callbacks, it is a static png.

Comment: Is there a way around it, or an alternative to notebook?